# Change class for selected div only

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I would like it to only change the class for the clicked `div`. Currently it will change the class for all `div`s. I have written this as a Blazor component.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    <div class="@divClass" @onclick="_ => ChangeDivClass()">@i</div>
}

@code 
{    
    String divClass;

    private void ChangeDivClass()
    {
        if (divClass == "red")
        {
            divClass = String.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            divClass = "red";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array instead of one variable.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < divClass.Length; i++)
 {
   var index = i;
   <div class="@divClass[i]" @onclick="_ => ChangeDivClass(index)">@i</div>
 }

@code 
 {    
   string[] divClass= new string[5];

   private void ChangeDivClass(int i)
    {
     if (divClass[i] == "red")
      {
        divClass[i] = String.Empty;
      }
     else
      {
        divClass[i] = "red";
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi what would I do if I didn't know the size of the array each time? Such as I passed in items from a parent and it was iterating in a foreach the divs?  Thanks

Comment: @HenkHolterman You were right it doesn't work. OMG, I never ever hear anything about it. for resolving this problem I edit the answer again and add a local variable in the loop, and in lambda expression using this local var. is it ok ?!

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi - I have corrected your edit. Look at where `i` can be used. `index` is only needed inside the lambda.

Answer (score 2):

try below code:

```
@if (items != null)
{
    @foreach (var item in items)
    {
        <div class="@RenderDomClass(item.Id)" @onclick="_ => ChangeColor(item.Id)">@item.Id</div>
    }
}

@functions{
    //Instead of these Mock data you should load your own data
    IList<Foo> items = new List<Foo>()
         {
            new Foo { Id =1, DomClasses=new List<string>(){string.Empty}},
            new Foo { Id =2, DomClasses=new List<string>(){string.Empty}},
            new Foo { Id =3, DomClasses=new List<string>(){string.Empty}},
            new Foo { Id =4, DomClasses=new List<string>(){string.Empty}},
            new Foo { Id =5, DomClasses=new List<string>(){string.Empty}},
            new Foo { Id =6, DomClasses=new List<string>(){string.Empty}},

        };

private void ChangeColor(int id)
{
    var domClasses = items.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Id == id).DomClasses;
    if (domClasses.Contains("red"))
    {
        domClasses.Remove("red");
    }
    else
    {
        domClasses.Add("red");
    }

    RenderDomClass(id);
}

private string RenderDomClass(int id)
{
    var domClass = string.Empty;
    var domClasses = items.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Id == id).DomClasses;
    if (domClasses.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in domClasses)
        {
            domClass += $" {item}";
        }
    }

    return domClass;
}


public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> DomClasses { get; set; }
}
}
```

The result of the above code is:

[image]

Fell free to ask question. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks Hamed, What if I was was passing in a List<Students> from a service and and it's properties are just Groups and names. l I'd like to be able to toggle the class to see the students in the groups.

Comment: You Just need simply, Change my `Foo` class, and create your Own `POCO` with each property that you want, then map your fetched data to this `POCO` and go on.

Answer (score 2):

Create a component for this behavior :

**CustomComponent.razor**

```cs
<div class="@divClass" @onclick="ChangeDivClass">@Value</div>
@code 
{    
    [Parameter]
    public int Value;

    string divClass;

    private void ChangeDivClass()
    {
        if (divClass == "red")
        {
            divClass = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            divClass = "red";
        }
    }
}
```

Your parent component become:

**ParentComponent.razor**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    <CustomComponet Value="@i" />
}
```