# Blazor how to target an element within a foreach loop

Tags: c#, blazor

I've made a page that queries results and shows it on a table. There is a field on this table that takes one of my queried results and decrypts it using a service I have created. My issue is that when I click on the button that decrypts the result within the table it universally shows the result on all table rows instead of the one table row that has been clicked. This is my code below, please have a look at the UnmaskPan method

```
@page "/"
@using TranactionJournalV4.Models;
@using TranactionJournalV4.Data;
@using TranactionJournalV4.Controllers;
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
@using System.Configuration;
@using Encryption_Handler;


@inject SearchService searchService
@inject SearchDropDownService searchDropDownService
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

@implements IDisposable
<EditForm Model="formValues" OnValidSubmit="@SearchTransactions">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <MatThemeProvider Theme="@theme">
        <div class="row formRow">
            <div class="col-12 text-center pb-4">

                <MatDatePicker Label="Transaction Date" @bind-Value="@formValues.startDate" EnableTime="true"></MatDatePicker>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formValues.startDate)" />

            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <MatSelect Label="Region" @bind-Value="@formValues.Region">
                    @foreach (var region in Regions)
                    {
                        <MatOptionString Value="@region.RegionCode.ToString()">@region.RegionName</MatOptionString>
                    }

                </MatSelect>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <MatSelect Label="MCC" @bind-Value="@formValues.Mcc">
                    @foreach (var MCode in MCCs)
                    {
                        <MatOptionString Value="@MCode.Mcc">@MCode.Mcc - @MCode.Description</MatOptionString>
                    }

                </MatSelect>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <MatTextField @bind-Value="@formValues.MerchantID" Label="Merchant ID"></MatTextField>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formValues.MerchantID)" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <MatSelect Label="Transaction Currency" @bind-Value="@formValues.CurrencyCode">
                    @foreach (var CCode in CurrencyCodes)
                    {
                        <MatOptionString Value="@CCode.Numeric">@CCode.Numeric - @CCode.ShortName</MatOptionString>
                    }

                </MatSelect>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <MatTextField @bind-Value="@formValues.TerminalID" Label="Terminal ID"></MatTextField>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formValues.TerminalID)" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <MatTextField @bind-Value="@formValues.TxnAmount" Label="Transaction Amount"></MatTextField>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <MatTextField maxlength="8" @bind-Value="@formValues.BIN" Label="BIN"></MatTextField>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formValues.BIN)" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <MatSelect Label="Message Type" @bind-Value="@formValues.MessageType">
                    @foreach (var MType in MessageTypes)
                    {
                        <MatOptionString Value="@MType.MessageType">@MType.MessageType - @MType.Description</MatOptionString>
                    }

                </MatSelect>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <MatTextField maxlength="19" @bind-Value="@formValues.MaskedPan" Label="Masked PAN"></MatTextField>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formValues.MaskedPan)" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <MatSelect Label="Processing Code" @bind-Value="@formValues.ProcessingCode">
                    @foreach (var procCode in ProcessingCodes)
                    {
                        <MatOptionString Value="@procCode.ProcessingCode"> @procCode.ProcessingCode - @procCode.Description</MatOptionString>
                    }


                </MatSelect>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <MatTextField maxlength="19" @bind-Value="@formValues.ClearPan" Label="Clear PAN"></MatTextField>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formValues.ClearPan)" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <MatSelect Label="Response Code" @bind-Value="@formValues.ResponseCode">
                    @foreach (var ResCode in ResponseCodes)
                    {
                        <MatOptionString Value="@ResCode.ResponseCode">@ResCode.ResponseCode - @ResCode.Description</MatOptionString>
                    }
                </MatSelect>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <MatTextField maxlength="6" @bind-Value="@formValues.AuthCode" Label="Authorization Code"></MatTextField>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formValues.AuthCode)" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center pb-4">
                <MatSelect Label="Entry Code" @bind-Value="@formValues.EntryCode">
                    @foreach (var entryCode in EntryModes)
                    {
                        <MatOptionString Value="@entryCode.EntryCode">@entryCode.EntryModeDescription</MatOptionString>
                    }

                </MatSelect>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-right pt-3">
            <div class="col-12 text-right">
                <MatButton Raised="true" Type="submit">Search</MatButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </MatThemeProvider>
</EditForm>
@if (transactions == null)
{

}
else
{

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Transaction Date</th>
                <th>Merchant ID</th>
                <th>Terminal ID</th>
                <th>Trace</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Currency</th>
                <th>Authorization Code</th>
                <th>Response Code</th>
                <th>Masked PAN</th>
                <th>PAN</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            @foreach (var transaction in NextTransactions)
            {
                <tr class="tableInfo">

                    <td>@transaction.TransactionDateTime</td>
                    <td>@transaction.MerchantID</td>
                    <td>@transaction.TerminalID</td>
                    <td>@transaction.SystemTrace</td>
                    <td>$@transaction.TransactionAmount</td>
                    <td>@transaction.Currency</td>
                    <td>@transaction.AuthorizationCode</td>
                    <td>@transaction.ResponseCode</td>
                    <td>@transaction.PANM</td>
                    <td id="@transaction.ID">@ClearPAN</td>
                    <td class="btn btn-warning" @onclick="@(e => UnmaskPan(transaction.IV, transaction.PAN))">Unmask</td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="12">
                        <MatAccordion Class="w-100">
                            <MatExpansionPanel>
                                <MatExpansionPanelSummary>
                                    <MatExpansionPanelHeader Class=" w-100 text-center">Details</MatExpansionPanelHeader>

                                </MatExpansionPanelSummary>
                                <MatExpansionPanelDetails>
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Acquirer ID</th>
                                                <th>Merchant Name</th>
                                                <th>MCC</th>
                                                <th>Message Type</th>
                                                <th>Processing Code</th>
                                                <th>Entry Mode</th>
                                                <th>Condition Code</th>
                                                <th>Network Transaction ID</th>
                                                <th>Network POS Data</th>
                                                <th>Service Code</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>@transaction.AcquirerID</td>
                                                <td>@transaction.MerchantNameAddress</td>
                                                <td>@transaction.MerchantCategoryCode</td>
                                                <td>@transaction.MessageType</td>
                                                <td>@transaction.ProcessingCode</td>
                                                <td>@transaction.PosEntryMode</td>
                                                <td>@transaction.PosConditionCode</td>
                                                <td>@transaction.NetworkTransactionID</td>
                                                <td>@transaction.NetworkPOSData</td>
                                                <td>@transaction.ServiceCode</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </MatExpansionPanelDetails>
                            </MatExpansionPanel>
                        </MatAccordion>
                    </td>
                </tr>



            }

        </tbody>

    </table>
    @if (StopLoading)
    {
        <div>
            <h4>End Of List</h4>
        </div>
    }
    <div id="list-end" class="mt-5 mb-5 p-5">
        <p></p>
        @if (IsLoading)
        {
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="spinner-grow" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;" role="status">
                    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

    </div>
    @*<input type="button" value="More Results" @onclick="@MoreResults" />*@
}







@code {
    MatTheme theme = new MatTheme()
    {
        Primary = "#002888",
        Secondary = "#EFD409"
    };
    FormValues formValues = new FormValues();
    public class FormValues
    {
        [Required]
        public DateTime startDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public string Region { get; set; }

        public string Mcc { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Merchant ID cannot be longer than 15 characters")]
        public string MerchantID { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Terminal ID cannot be longer than 8 characters")]
        public string TerminalID { get; set; }
        public decimal TxnAmount { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "BIN must be numeric")]
        public string BIN { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Masked PAN must be numeric")]
        public string MaskedPan { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Clear PAN must be numeric")]
        public string ClearPan { get; set; }
        public string AuthCode { get; set; }
        public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
        public string MessageType { get; set; }
        public string ProcessingCode { get; set; }
        public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
        public string EntryCode { get; set; }
    }
    private List<TransactionModel> transactions { get; set; }
    private PaginationDTO pagination = new PaginationDTO();
    private List<TransactionModel> NextTransactions = new List<TransactionModel>();
    private string ClearPAN;
    public string txnID { get; set; }

    public List<CommonMerchantCatagoryCodes> MCCs;
    public List<CommonCurrencyCodes> CurrencyCodes;
    public List<CommonPosmessageTypeRecords> MessageTypes;
    public List<CommonPosprocessingCodeRecords> ProcessingCodes;
    public List<CommonResponseCodeRecords> ResponseCodes;

    public List<EntryModes> EntryModes = new List<EntryModes>
{
        new EntryModes{EntryCode= "05", EntryModeDescription = "Chip Card"},
        new EntryModes{EntryCode= "92", EntryModeDescription = "Chip Card - Fallback"},
        new EntryModes{EntryCode= "02", EntryModeDescription = "Magnetic Stripe"},
        new EntryModes{EntryCode= "94", EntryModeDescription = "Magnetic Stripe - No AID"},
        new EntryModes{EntryCode= "01", EntryModeDescription = "Manually Keyed"},
        new EntryModes{EntryCode= "07", EntryModeDescription = "NFC"}
    };

    public List<Regions> Regions = new List<Regions>
{
        new Regions{RegionCode = "419733", RegionName = "Antigua and Barbuda (05)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "457947", RegionName = "Aruba (16)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "457944", RegionName = "Bahamas (02)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "457944", RegionName = "Bahamas - Agency (32)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "483172", RegionName = "Barbados (15)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "419640", RegionName = "Bonaire (17)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "457946", RegionName = "Cayman Islands (07)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "419639", RegionName = "Curaçao (13)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "483174", RegionName = "Grenada (09)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "419641", RegionName = "Saba (18)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "419735", RegionName = "Saint Kitts and Nevis (11)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "419736", RegionName = "Saint Lucia (12)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "483173", RegionName = "Saint Vincent (20)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "419638", RegionName = "Sint Maarten (Dutch part) (19)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "415536", RegionName = "Trinidad and Tobago (03)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "457945", RegionName = "Turks and Caicos Islands (14)"},

    };



    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        MCCs = searchDropDownService.GetAllMCCs().ToList();
        CurrencyCodes = searchDropDownService.GetAllCurrencies().ToList();
        MessageTypes = searchDropDownService.GetAllMessages().ToList();
        ProcessingCodes = searchDropDownService.GetAllProcessingCodes().ToList();
        ResponseCodes = searchDropDownService.GetAllResponseCodes().ToList();
    }

    async Task SearchTransactions()
    {


        NextTransactions.Clear();
        await LoadMore();
        await InitJsListenerAsync();
    }


    bool IsLoading { get; set; } = false;

    //int PageSize = 30;

    int PageNumber = 0;

    bool StopLoading = false;



    protected async Task InitJsListenerAsync()
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ScrollList.Init", "list-end", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public async Task LoadMore()
    {
        if (!IsLoading)
        {
            IsLoading = true;

            StateHasChanged();

            await Task.Delay(1000);

            //for (int i = 0; i < pagination.Page; i++)

            transactions = await searchService.SearchNextResults(formValues.startDate, formValues.Region, formValues.Mcc, formValues.MerchantID, formValues.CurrencyCode, formValues.TerminalID, formValues.TxnAmount, formValues.BIN, formValues.MessageType, formValues.MaskedPan, formValues.ProcessingCode, formValues.ClearPan, formValues.ResponseCode, formValues.AuthCode, formValues.EntryCode, pagination);
            //}
            pagination.Page++;

            foreach (var txn in transactions)
            {
                NextTransactions.Add(txn);
            }
            PageNumber++;

            IsLoading = false;

            StateHasChanged();


            //at the end of pages or results stop loading anymore
            if (PageNumber > 50)
            {
                await StopListener();
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task StopListener()
    {
        StopLoading = true;
        IsLoading = false;
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ScrollList.RemoveListener");
        StateHasChanged();
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ScrollList.RemoveListener");
    }

    protected void UnmaskPan(string IV, string PAN)
    {

        ExcryptProvider exp = new ExcryptProvider("10.61.131.14", 9000, false);

        try
        {
            var currentRecord = exp.DecryptASCIICBC(searchDropDownService.GetDataEncryptionKey().ToString(), IV, PAN).Replace("\0", string.Empty);
            ClearPAN = currentRecord;


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            var currentRecord = "Decryption Error";
            ClearPAN = currentRecord;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @HenkHolterman the only issue I have is when I click the unmask button because ClearPan is a universal variable its result populates all table rows instead of just the one table row I have clicked. I can't think of a way to target a specific table row when I click the button in that row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change class for selected div only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60295220/change-class-for-selected-div-only)

Comment: Yes it does thank you!